# Using Fork for Command Line Arguements

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I'm trying to execute the command "ls -l" but I'm not exactly sure how to approach it.

This is what I've tried:

```
int main(void) {
    char * input;
    char * args[2];
    char buff[100];

    input = malloc(sizeof(buff));

while(fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin) != NULL) {

    printf("Enter a command\n");

    if(strcmp(input,"ls -l\n") ==0) {
        pid_t childPid;

        childPid = fork();

        if(childPid == 0) {
            args[0] = "/bin/ls -l";
            args[1] = NULL;

            execv(args[0],args);
    }

}

}

free(input);
}
```

However, the command doesn't seem to work here. It works if I just simply use "ls" but I want to use "ls -l" is there another argument I have to pass to get this to work?

Comment: Talk about biting off more than you can chew! Get the basics going first then add in all the dynamic memory and string compares etc. Without looking at `man execv` I'm guessing the `-l` should be passed as `args[1]` and not added to `args[0]`

Comment: I I tried that but to which exec?

Comment: I'd have to look at the manual pages to check - you can do the same!

Comment: Hmm so I think execvp would work. I'm not sure how to pass the arguements though, say : args[0] = "/bin/ls"; args[1] = "-l";  Then calling it as such: execvp(args[0],args); doesn't work. As that gives me "cannot access" errors.

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting the same error, is there possibly soposed to be a space in the args[1] = "-l"; string?

Comment: @EDEDE How's `execvp(3)` supposed to know how many elements `args` has?

Comment: No idea, I'm just learning about this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to understand this simple example.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

    /* status of child execution */
    int status;
    /* pointer * to array of char*(strings)*/
    char ** args;

    /* allocate memory for three char*(stings) */
    args = (char**) malloc( 3 * sizeof(char*) );

    /* fork program and store each fork id */
    pid_t childPid = fork();

    /* if this is child process */
    if(childPid == 0) {

        args[0] = "ls";
        args[1] = "-l";
        args[2] = NULL;

        /* execute args[0] command with args arguments */
        execvp(args[0],args);

        /* send execution code 0 to parent and terminate child */
        exit(0);

    } else {

        /* wait execution code from child*/
        wait(&status);

        /* free allocated space */
        free(input);
        free(args);

        /* exit program with received code from child */
        exit(status);
    }

}
```

I commented every line, but tell me if you want more informations.
You have to understand how to execute commands from child and inform parent before continue to user's input commands.

Answer (score 2):

When you call any of the `exec()` variants, you have to pass each argument separately, as in

```
args[0] = "/bin/ls";
args[1] = "-l";
args[2] = NULL;
```

Comment: Yeah it was the fact that I forgot to NullTerminate the last string, thanks.